# Are "complex" answers a bad thing?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious about something that happened recently on an answer I posted a month or so ago. Last night, a user randomly commented on my answer with abusive language. I've never encountered this person before so I'm not sure where it came from. The user commented saying that my "answer is shit" because "basically you just tell people to upgrade", along with other things.

I flagged the comment, it was deleted. The user then attempted to delete around 90% of my answer, which was all extra information I added in about pitfalls of upgrading mono on Ubuntu (the solution was to upgrade mono). The original question asked about OSX and Gentoo, but I added this information because I know of it from experience and am thinking of others who will encounter the post with the same issue. Anyway, I flagged this edit and rolled it back. What happened next is what has left me puzzled and is the inspiration for this post. The mod said:

> @ABUSIVE_USER If you think an answer is too complex, downvote it and
>   post your own answer. Don't remove vast quantities of it or make such
>   remarks as you did.

This didn't chastise the user, but rather reads like an endorsement. This isn't my own assumption, it's supported by the fact that the user then downvoted me, did a "copy and paste" style answer on the same question that simply includes a hyperlink to more information, the information I posted in my answer. The user then began a series of long comments on my answer about how and why his answer is so much better.

I tagged the mod in a comment asking if this is the new policy, to punish good answers that are "complex" for having too much information, and to simply post links so they can rot. No answer. So I'm curious here, has the policy completely turned around since last I was active?

Comment: Not sure if asking said person who made you frustrated if they have some "diagnosed issue" is particularly productive in general.

Comment: @DonkeyKong Yes, it was not productive. I lost patience and made a mildly offensive remark after being subjected to a random attack and then having to read comment after comment of illogical justification for it. I'm not a saint, sorry. I didn't delete the comment because 1) the comment isn't the question here and 2) I'm not going to try to hide anything I did in the situation.

Comment: If the other user copy-pasted your answer without giving you any credit, that is plagiarism and is also not okay by site rules (even if he did delete a lot of the content). Not sure if you want to pursue that or not, but I thought I'd put that out there.

Comment: @MageXy I put "copy and paste" in quotes and added "style" because it wasn't a direct copy and paste. What I was meaning to imply was that they took information directly from my answer, and added nothing to the answer they downvoted and complained about, except an opening statement that "some people" found this solution. Wasn't a `ctrl+c, ctrl+v`, just to clarify.

Comment: Looking at the answer IMO this really isn't "overly complex", I mean it takes hardly half a minute to read (which is funny because the editing persons answer seems to be even more complex to me, but well). Some of my answer are 10-20 times as long and except for one time (where it was justified) no one complained. So I guess you just had bad luck, keep up the good work :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire I'd be very interested in seeing this answer of yours

Comment: @Magisch - Its pretty easy to find but its since been cleaned up and there isn't a lot left of the dispute (nothing except an edit revision for <10k)

Comment: Complex answers are only bad if the person who asked the question (and future readers) cannot understand them.

Comment: I don't get it how down voting a complex answer is a good thing, I usually get comments on my detailed answers that *"-1, too briefly answered"* .. but that's not what I expect from a user, if he is not good with that, just move to next answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien well there are answers you have to read three times to find out if they are even tangenting your problem or not - so I can understand if some people downvote these

Comment: I can remember down-voting one answer for being too complex because the question was very noob-like and the given answer included some unnecessary details that average noob would never know about and such answer would only confuse the person more. There was other answers that was a lot more on the spot, more concise, easy to understand by anyone.

Comment: @Rhayene I think than downvote and upvotes are getting more on personal experience rather than a contribution in a whole... if I am not able to get the answer but it's correct, than its me who is not good enough to grasp the logic there, nothing to blame other user who answered :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien one could argue that an answer where you have to puzzle the relevant pieces together from a whole novel of additional information is not as helpful as an answer that has a clear answering part and then provides the additional information

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> I tagged the mod in a comment asking if this is the new policy, to
>   punish good answers that are "complex" for having too much
>   information, and to simply post links so they can rot.

The policy is to down vote answers if you think they're not useful, not to go off on an extended conversation or rant in the comments. Telling a user the correct way to express their opinion on a post is not the same thing as endorsing or agreeing with their opinion.

As Servy said, whether being too complex prevents a post from being useful or not is up to the individual user. The only things the site has a policy against for answers are:

- Not actually being an answer to *any* question
- Link only posts
- Rude or abusive posts
- SPAM

By "policy" I mean there are flag options for these so the site clearly doesn't want them happening. Anything else comes down to the opinion of the community.

Comment: I agree with you, my question however is that the definition of "not useful" was explicitly defined as "too complex". My question is if this is an accurate definition.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Users are free to use whatever criteria they want to determine how useful they think a post is.  If someone feels that a post is so complex that it's not useful, that's a perfectly valid opinion to present.  If someone else feels that the post is useful despite, or because of, it's complexity, that it *also* a valid opinion that they're free to express.

Comment: @Servy Yeah you're right, I guess I was just caught off guard by the mod giving it as a reason. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire The mod merely stated, "If that is your opinion, this is the correct way to express that opinion".  He made no commentary on whether he agreed with that opinion, or whether it's a widely held opinion.  In this case, if someone feels that an answer is low quality because it is overly complex and contains a significant amount of information that they feel isn't relevant, the correct way to express that opinion is a vote (and possibly a comment), rather than a radical edit.  The mod is in no way stating whether he feels the answer is too complex or not.

Comment: @Servy got it, marked an answer as accepted and even upvoted your previous comment.

Answer (score 26):

**TL;DR** Provide a summary of your complex answer so that those who don't want to read all of it can still easily find your answer.

> This didn't chastise the user, but rather reads like an endorsement. This isn't my own assumption, it's supported by the fact that the user then downvoted me, did a "copy and paste" style answer on the same question that simply includes a hyperlink to more information, the information I posted in my answer. The user then began a series of long comments on my answer about how and why his answer is so much better.

The mods are not endorsing the opinion of the offensive comment.  They stepped in because of the offensive comment and promptly laid down the law. Offensive content is not acceptable.  They then offered an alternative that is within the rules of the site, which the other user actually acted on.  In this case, the system is working as expected.  Another user found your answer hard to read and downvoted it.  That's why downvotes exist.  If another user comes along and finds your answer comprehensive and understandable, they can upvote it.

You should follow the mods' advice and also downvote answers that you feel are not helpful.  So if another answer makes unhelpful claims about your answer, feel free to downvote it.  If the other answer is truly link-only with no actual content, then you can edit it or flag it accordingly.

> I tagged the mod in a comment asking if this is the new policy, to punish good answers that are "complex" for having too much information, and to simply post links so they can rot.

Complex answer are perfectly acceptable.  *Overly complex* answers are less useful and can attract downvotes.  It's all about the scope of knowledge that the question requires.  If your answer is overly complex, it becomes hard to see the actual solution.  Tangential information is not particularly helpful and only distracts readers from the actual answer.  There is plenty of room on the spectrum of complexity between a link-only answer and an entire blog post.  You just have to find the right amount of information to provide.  To this end, it could be useful to reformat your complex answer to include a TL;DR for lazy readers.  That way it's immediately apparent what "the answer" is but you have the rest of the complex post to explain in depth.

Comment: This is an overly long answer. TLDR TLDR, and you're golden.

Comment: @DeerHunter a question about why a complex answer is downvoted receives a *complex post* as answer.

Comment: _«include a TL;DR» seems like a valuable advice to me!_ This way the answer can offer a short summary (most important points and the actual solution) as well as an in-depth analysis or further information. The second part can be complex without making the overall answer less useful. Quasi a win-win situation for the easy-fast-lazy reader and the eager one.

Comment: @DeerHunter I have now followed my own advice.

Comment: I often write long answers, and try to either put a TL;DR or **bold** some key phrases.  I try to highlight things that will make sense to people that don't need the surrounding background explanation.  `---` horizontal lines are great.  Remember, for some questions, **the target audience for answers includes a lot of people who will be skimming**.  It's not a bad thing for people to skim to see if the post is the kind of thing they're looking for.  Don't expect every reader of your answer to be interested in everything the OP was confused about, so separate points that can be separated.

Comment: I like to bold an introduction/abstract at the top of my longer answers, which serves as a sort of organic "tl;dr".

Comment: In fact I've just noticed that @PeterCordes did precisely that to the answer in question [sic (lol)], and it works really well!

Answer (score 8):

Somehow, I do not agree with what the other answerers said about "complex answers" not being "helpful". Yes, including a summary is always nice and helps when people are in hurry, but complex answers (if not off-topic) are always awesome. They provide in-depth knowledge that will help one to understand why/how/when things work.

I feel bad for you and let me assure you from my side that, everytime I see a great post, I always upvote it and/or favorite it.

Comment: Nobody wrote that complex answers are necessarily not useful. It was stated that an individual may consider an answer unhelpful because of it's complexity, which is that person's right. Another answer says that *overly complex* answers are not helpful, which I also agree with: to explain something in a complicated way that could be explained simpler is not useful.

Comment: well @Stibu that's the thing. Information is always great. It might not be useful for a particular person, but it can be of great help for others. In such cases, why not just stay away from that particular solution/answer? Why neg-vote it? Ofcourse, I will also downvote if the answer is off-topic.

Comment: if you say.. let's push it down.. upvotes on other answers will push it down anyway..

Comment: @guest420420 `Information is always great.` That is false.  Not all information is useful.  There's *lots* of things that you can put in an answer that are actively harmful, or at a minimum, a waste of the reader's time.  It's absolutely possible, and actually quite common, for an answer to contain way more information than it should, and as a direct result, convey *less* information to readers.

Comment: Well I did mention about the answer being "on-topic" right, @Servy? "off-topic"/"wrong" answers are not welcome anyway, but I have actually seen some answers being down-voted simply because the reader din't have a clue what the answerer was talking about. It should be called as ignorance..

Comment: @guest420420 If the reader can't understand the answer, then it's a pretty strong sign that the answer isn't clear, which is a good reason to downvote it.  An answer that fails to effectively communicate the information in it *isn't a useful answer* and the votes should reflect that.

Comment: @Servy, while what you are saying is correct, they should atleast mention why they downvote it. Without an explanation, it is simply rude to do that. Don't you think so?

Comment: @guest420420 No, it's not rude at all.  They are under no obligation to post a comment at all.  If they would like to, they certainly can, but if they choose not to, that's perfectly fine.

Answer (score 6):

People have the right to downvote content they see as not good.  Mods advising people to do so rather than deface content is not endorsement of the downvote.  It is redirectiong disagreement to acceptable channels.

---

If they think your content is bad because of its complexity, they can downvote.  They should *not* abusively attack you.  They should *not* edit your post extensively in ways that don't match your clear intention.

Disagreement is allowed.  They *should* be encouraged to disagree in the acceptable way (downvoting, alternative answers), instead of vandalism and swear words.  That doesn't mean the mod thinks the disagreement is justified.

And yes, they can copy/paste (with attribution) your content into a simpler answer.  If that results in a better answer, it may even get more upvotes.

For complex answers, it is usually a good idea to start with the simple solution.  Then put in a divider using `---` and clearly say that the rest can be skipped, and provides background/additional information.

That puts the high value up front, which makes an answer better.

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the rude words, I agree with the "abusive user". The problem wasn't that your answer was "complex" (which isn't inherently a problem), it was that:

> His answer is doing the wrong thing: explaining how to upgrade Mono, which is unrelated to the question. Upgrading mono is already explained in the official source that he and I link too, and if he copy+pastes it it will get out of date pretty quickly.

*How* to upgrade Mono is something I would definitely recommend abstracting away from an answer that is, fundamentally, "this is a bug and you need to upgrade to at least vX.Y.Z".

I see this whole drama as a textbook example of how starting off an interaction with "violence" can turn what might otherwise have been a useful and helpful discussion into a complete nightmare, often with no positive progress at the end of it. Fortunately, as it happens, the "abusive user" has since come back and written a second, even better version of his or her replacement answer.

If it weren't for the fact that it's already been through the social ringer, *I'd* probably edit the upgrade instructions out of your answer.